# John Wick Chapter 2 bounty question

Tags: plot-explanation, john-wick, john-wick-chapter-2

Everyone went after John wick got the 7 million bounty before he got Excommunicado. Near the end, why did they wait for him to get Excommunicado before trying to kill him for the 14 million bounty?

It's just a bounty after all just different prices, so why wait for 1 hour?

Answer (score 2):

The bounty was originally offered by Santino and lifted after Wick finished the job.
Winston had to make a decision to excommunicado Wick because he broke the rules by killing Santino on Continental grounds. So as long as the bounty offer had been active, everybody tried to win it. That's why everyone was trying to kill Wick. After it was retracted, I think assassins went their own way, went looking for jobs, etc..

After the excommunicado, it's a whole different story. Winston gave Wick a one hour head start to get ready/be prepared.